# cfftp and self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, coldfusion, ftp

I'm having trouble getting ColdFusion to connect to a secure FTP server that uses a self-signed certificate. The connection just times out. I've tested the setup in an FTP client and it works, but you must accept an 'unknown certificate.'

The code, though it's not very helpful:

```
<cfftp
    connection="ftp"
    action="open"
    server="server"
    username="username"
    password="password"
    port="23456"
    passive="true"
    secure="true"
/>
```

Here's the error I get from ColdFusion:

`Verify your connection attributes: username, password, server, fingerprint, port, key, connection, proxyServer, and secure (as applicable). Error: Session.connect: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out.`

Does anyone know if it's possible to accept the certificate? Or if that's even the problem?

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure about `cfftp` but for `cfhttp` requests to sites with a self-signed certificate you have to import their certificate into the Java keystore on your ColdFusion server. So you might want to give that a try.

I always export the certificate in DER format

The command to import should be something like this:

```
keytool -import -v -alias giveUniqueName -file filename.cer -keystore cacerts -storepass thePassword
```

Here is the command line to verify an imported certificate:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts -alias giveUniqueName -storepass thePassword
```

*I did not include the password here but am pretty sure you can Google it.  If not, send me a message and I can give it to you.*

Also, you may need to supply pathing information depending on where you run the keytool commands from and where your certificate file resides.

Another note, be sure you are updating the correct cacerts file that ColdFusion is using.  In case you have more than one JRE installed on that server.  You can verify the JRE ColdFusion is using from the administrator under the 'System Information'.  Look for the `Java Home` line.

Oh - and you have to restart ColdFusion after making the import.

***UPDATE FOR CF10***

I found a forum discussion ([here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4246821)) talking about installing certificates on CF10.  The `keytool` commands appear to be slightly different in their example.  In case it is a bit different than CF9, here is what they said:

```
keytool -importcert -alias giveUniqueName -trustcacerts -file filename.cer -keystore cacerts -storepass thePassword
Trust this certificate? [no]:  y
```

It looks like the verification command line has not changed.